# Why editing post does not freeze edit option

Tags: discussion, edits

While I was editing this question [Why can't i get the result by full-text index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178773/why-cant-i-get-the-result-by-full-text-index)

Someone also editing that question same time, when I was submitted my editing its show me to post is edited click to reload when I was clicked same with manner changes done by other users appears.

As well as its show to 2 editing history,

1) revision by Alex https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47178773/4

2) revision by me   https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47178773/5

and posting of edit for both are same

so How to Avoid this because its maintaining history, as well as time wasting of a community member

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it's an unfortunate side-effect, but locking posts being edited by others doesn't make any sense in a community the scale of Stack Overflow.

- someone locking the post and forgetting about it might lock out a community member who actually has an edit to make, or a much better one. No one is going to wait around for an undefined period of time until they can finally make their edit. This is likely to do much more damage than an edit getting occasionally overwritten by someone faster - in which case you can always merge in your edits, as far as they're still relevant.
- a lock feature could be misused to prevent editing out bad/offensive/evil stuff, for example - you'd just need a second account locking your post.